# Trim leading and trailing punctuation characters from a Java string

Tags: java

Can someone kindly suggest a succinct/elegant way to trim leading and trailing punctuation characters (Java regex `\p{Punct}` or POSIX regex `[:punct:]`) from a Java string?  Punctuation characters that are within the string "body" (i.e. between the first and the last non-punctuation characters in the string) are to be retained.

I did get it kinda working by converting the String to a character array and looping in the forwards and backwards direction and skipping over the punctuation characters, until the first non-punctuation character is encountered.  However, I feel that there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a duplicate. I posted my answer over there instead.

Comment: @dnault - I thought your answer was better - I retracted my flag. Now [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62586907/12567365) to that answer!